# a Matrix that returns the average of a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics, quadratic-forms

Let's concentrate in the 2 dimensional case. I'm looking for a $2 \times 2$ Matrix $A$ that for a vector $x=(x_1, x_2)$ will satisfy: 
$$ xAx^t = \frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$$

Using simple methods of quadratic forms, I was able to find a matrix that returns the $\text{(average)}^2$ of a vector. which is:
$$ B = \begin{bmatrix}
    0.25 & 0.25 \\
    0.25 & 0.25 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
And indeed if $x=(5,9)$ than $ xBx^t = 49 = 7^2$. And if I not mistaken, the general case $n$ dimensions is as simple to solve. we will end up with a matrix where  $a_{ij} = \frac{1}{n^2}$ for every $0 \leq i,j \leq n$

Now, when I try to create a matrix that returns the mean, I encounter some problems. I know that if such a matrix indeed exist, I think it should be in the form:
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    b & a \\
\end{bmatrix}$$ and we can also understand that $2a+2b$ = $1$ than it appears we can try and solve the equation for $a$ to see if such an $a$ exist. But I just have to think there has to be simple way to find the Matrix if it exsist, or to tell pretty fast that there is no such a matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such matrix exists, because the scaling is wrong. If you replace the vector $x$ by the vector $\lambda x$, the right side is multiplied by $\lambda$; however, the left side is multiplied by $\lambda^2$.

Comment: thank for the simple answer. I'm little embarrassed I did not see it...

Comment: It takes practice - it's a good test for *any* inequality that looks sketchy.

Comment: if I have a function that satisfied $f(\delta x) = \delta^2 f(x)$ than I can always find a Matrix that gives me $f$ ?

Comment: @d_e: check out [quadratic forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form).